I'm setting up email themes in keycloak: it shows error Couldn't find template in cache for "text/email-test.ftl"
I am setting up email themes in keycloak. When I test the email connection in the <Realm Settings> menu option and then the <Email> tab option and press the <Test Connection> button, the following error is observed in the log:
> 2024-09-16 23:21:45,305 FINE \[freemarker.cache\] (executor-thread-70) Couldn't find template in cache for "text/email-test.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
> 2024-09-16 23:21:45,305 FINE \[freemarker.cache\] (executor-thread-70) TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("text/email-test_en_US.ftl"): Not found
> 2024-09-16 23:21:45,306 FINE \[freemarker.cache\] (executor-thread-70) TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("text/email-test_en.ftl"): Not found 2024-09-16 23:21:45,306 FINE \[freemarker.cache\] (executor-thread-70) TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("text/email-test.ftl"): Not found org.keyc loak.email.EmailException: Failed to template email at org.keycloak.email.freemarker.FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.processTemplate(FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java:247) at org.keycloak.email.freemarker.FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.sendSmtpTestEmail(FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java:12 6) at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.RealmAdminResource.testSMTPConnection(RealmAdminResource.java:1008) at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.RealmAdminResource$quarkusrestinvoker$testSMTPConnection_0bc3cac9c894e7b29eb4c1f2d80a099cba7bd f38.invoke(Unknown Source)

I created the files indicated in the error: email-test_en_US.ftl, email-test_en.ftl and email-test.ftl, however the error persists.
Does anyone know how to fix this error?
I appreciate your help
